# Fragments vs. Activities: What is a better practise: to have 2 fragments or 2 Activities in Android Studio Application

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I would like to know what is a better practise: to have 2 fragments or 2 Activities in Android Studio Application and the reason **why** ? In which case 2 fragments and in which 2 activities ?